# Simple function of quantmod not working anymore

Tags: r, quantmod

I am turning in my thesis tomorow and I'm getting a very bizzare error message with quantmod which I never had during the last weeks while working with this package. I can't manage to import data specificly of Dow Jones index (^DJI). I get the following error message:

```
getSymbols("^DJI",src="yahoo", from='2005-6-01', to='2012-6-21')

Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
impossible to open the URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^DJI&a=5&b=01&c=2005&d=5&e=21&f=2012&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=^DJI&x=.csv'
Also : Message d'avis :
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
impossible to open : the status HTTP was '404 Not Found'
```

I almost feel embarased to ask such a simple question. I really don't understand where the problem is.. these for example work just fine

```
getSymbols("AAPL",src="yahoo", from='2005-6-01', to='2012-6-21')
getSymbols("^NDX",src="yahoo", from='2005-6-01', to='2012-6-21')
```

So where is the problem? thank you very much for your help I really appreciate it !

Comment: And puzzling about methods the day before a thesis is turned in is ... ?

Comment: @GSee thanks for the comment, I am new to this website and missed out on that! for sure going to go correct that :) 
Edit: just noticed you are the one that did for me that great code for calculating the dividend yield! thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For some reason, yahoo does not currently provide that data.  You can see
[on the yahoo website](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EDJI+Historical+Prices)
that it currently says 
"Historical quote data is unavailable for the specified date range."

I do not know ifthis is temporary or permanent, but I would guess that it is 
temparary because as you noted, "^NDX" still works.  Since today is a holiday in the United States, it is possible that Yahoo is doing maintenance.

If it becomes available before it is too late for you, I would suggest saving the data
either with `save` or with `FinancialInstrument:::saveSymbols.common` so that
you could load it back using `getSymbols(*, src='FI')`

If it's not up by the time you need it, you have a couple alternatives that may or may not suit your needs.  You could use `getSymbols.FRED` to get the closing values of the index since 1886

```
getSymbols("DJIA", src='FRED')
```

Or, you could use the DIA ETF which is actually tradeable and is a decent proxy 
for the index

```
getSymbols("DIA", src='yahoo')
```