# Quantmod, getSymbols error trying to replicate answer

Tags: r, quantmod

I just downloaded the package `Quantmod` and have been playing with `getSymbols`. I want to be able to get data for multiple stocks as in this question: [getSymbols and using lapply, Cl, and merge to extract close prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574595/getsymbols-and-using-lapply-cl-and-merge-to-extract-close-prices).

Unfortuantely, when I try to duplicate the answer:

```
tickers <- c("SPY","DIA","IWM","SMH","OIH","XLY",
         "XLP","XLE","XLI","XLB","XLK","XLU")
getSymbols(tickers, from="2001-03-01", to="2011-03-11")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
cannot open URL 
'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=2&b=01&c=2001&d=2&e=11&f=2011&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=SPY&x=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,
: cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (null)'
```

Here is my sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-0 TTR_0.22-0     xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-10     Defaults_1.1-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.2      lattice_0.20-23 tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: could have the same reason as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337249/simple-function-of-quantmod-not-working-anymore)

Comment: potentially... changing the src to google works okay.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in r610 of R-Forge. This question should be closed/deleted because SO isn't the appropriate forum for bug reports (or issues with Yahoo's servers).

Comment: I'm not sure r610 of R-Forge, but the issue was using R downloaded yesterday and Quantmod downloaded yesterday

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaUlrich, works fine. @user2492310: try `install.packages("quantmod",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")`

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** In response to OP's comment:

So the bottom line seems to be that sites which provide free downloads of historical data are quirky, to say the least. They do not necessarily work for all valid symbols, and sometimes they become unavailable for no apparent reason. `ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv` worked for me 24 hours ago, but does not work (for me) at the moment. This may be because Yahoo has imposed a 24 hour lockout on my IP, which they will do if they detect activity interpretable as a DDOS attack. Or it might be for some other reason...

The updated code below, which queries Google, does work (again, at the moment), for everything except DJIA. Note that there is more success if you specify the exchange and the symbol (`EXCHANGE:SYMBOL`). I was unable to download SMH without the exchange. Finally, if your are having problems try uncommenting the print statement and pasting the url into a browser to see what happens.

```
tickers <- c("SPY","DJIA","IWM","NYSEARCA:SMH","OIH","XLY",
             "XLP","XLE","XLI","XLB","XLK","XLU")

g <- function(x,from,to,output="csv") {
  uri      <- "http://www.google.com/finance/historical"
  q.symbol <- paste("q",x,sep="=")
  q.from   <- paste("startdate",from,sep="=")
  q.to     <- paste("enddate",to,sep="=")
  q.output <- paste("output",output,sep="=")
  query    <- paste(q.symbol,q.output,q.from,q.to,sep="&")
  url      <- paste(uri,query,sep="?")
  # print(url)
  try(assign(x,read.csv(url),envir=.GlobalEnv))
}
lapply(tickers,g,from="2001-03-01",to="2011-03-11",output="csv")
```

You can download DJI from the St. Louis Fed, which is very reliable. Unfortunately, you get all of it (from 1896), and it's a time series.

```
getSymbols("DJIA",src="FRED")
```

**Original Response:**

This worked for me, for everything except SMH and OIH.

```
tickers <- c("SPY","DJIA","IWM","SMH","OIH","XLY",
                             "XLP","XLE","XLI","XLB","XLK","XLU")

f <- function(x) {
  uri    <- "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv"
  symbol <- paste("s",x,sep="=")
  from   <- "a=2&b=1&c=2001"
  to     <- "d=2&e=11&f=2011"
  period <- "g=d"
  ignore <- "ignore=.csv"
  query  <- paste(symbol,from,to,period,ignore,sep="&")
  url    <- paste(uri,query,sep="?")
  try(assign(x,read.csv(url),envir=.GlobalEnv))
}
lapply(tickers,f)
```

The main difference between this and `getSymbols(...)` is that this uses `ichart.yahoo.com` (as documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvHistQuotesDownload)), whereas `getSymbols(...)` uses `chart.yahoo.com`. The former seems to be much more reliable. In my experience, using `getSymbols(...)` with Yahoo is a monumental headache.

If the suggestion of @user2492310, to use `src="google"` works for you, then clearly this is the way to go. It didn't work for me.

One other note: SMH and OIH did not exist in 2001. The others all go back to at least 2000. So it might be that ichart.yahoo.com (and chart.yahoo.com) throws an error if you provide a date range outside of the symbol's operating range.

Comment: Numerous errors in your solution...`In file(file, "rt") : unable to connect to 'ichart.yahoo.com' on port 80.
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`

Comment: Yes it fails for me now as well. This exact code ran for me last night. If you go to the link I provided, which is managed by Yahoo, their example does not work either (it worked last night...). So I'm thinking they might throttle access under high loads(??). I know Google does that.

Comment: use:  yahoo.URL <- "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?" . it works like a charm

Comment: @SilverSpoon -  The code above does use that url. And today it works; yesterday it did not. That's the point - Google is more reliable.

Comment: in my case "ichart.yahoo.com" doesnt work but "ichart.finance.yahoo.com" (with "finance" word) does. It has nv failed me. Yes, alternatively, you can use google.

Comment: @SilverSpoon - Thanks. Yes, I see what you mean. I'll try that.