# quantmod's getSymbols no longer working

Tags: r, quantmod

I use the excellent quantmod to load stock prices from yahoo. This has never caused me any problems. However ever since yesterday I can not download any more stock quotes.

I also tried the get.hist.quote function from the tseries package but this gives me about the same error.

Below is the code that I tried:

```
library('quantmod','PerformanceAnalytics')   
tickers = '^GSPC'

data <- new.env()
getSymbols(tickers, src = 'yahoo', from = '1970-01-01', env = data, auto.assign = T)
```

This gave the following error:

> Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=",
>   from.m,  :    cannot open URL
>   'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC&a=0&b=01&c=1970&d=0&e=02&f=2014&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=^GSPC&x=.csv'
>   In addition: Warning message: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=",
>   Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :   InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A
>   connection with the server could not be established'

As far as I can see the link to yahoo finance doesn't work anymore (I also tried copy pasting the link to chrome but there I can't open it either).

Does anyone know what happend? Did yahoo finance change or am I missing an update from quantmod or something?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Had you searched, or just looked at the quantmod-tagged questions, you would have saved yourself some time.

Comment: Since this seems to be time-dependent, I re-ran both answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850143/quantmod-getsymbols-error-trying-to-replicate-answer) today (2014-01-02). Google worked, Yahoo did not.

Comment: @jlhoward: it's not time-dependent, your solution is simply wrong. ;)  My patch on R-Forge still works.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - Provide a link to the patch please.