# R - xts object encountering character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r, xts, posixct, posixlt

I was trying to replicate the momentum strategy by [rbresearch](https://rbresearch.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/momentum-in-r-part-2/) with S&P 500 companies. However it turned out that `getSymbols` was not able to grab price data for all tickers and I only got around 300 stocks by using:

```
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo', index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"), from='2000-01-01', to = '2015-12-31')
```

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850143/quantmod-getsymbols-error-trying-to-replicate-answer) discussing about this issue and it might be coming from the source "chart.yahoo.com". Therefore I adopted the method suggested by [jlhoward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985007/jlhoward) and it seemed to work perfectly without warnings.

UPDATE: After checking `quantmod` package, I found it is also grabbing data from ichart.yahoo.com now.

However when it comes to calculating the monthly close, an error read like,

```
Error in try.xts(x) : 
  Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
Called from: try.xts(x)
```

Here are my questions and what I don't understand:

<s>1) Is there a possible way to direct getSymbols to "ichart.yahoo.com" which gives more reliable quotes?</s>

2) I have converted all symbols to xts objects so why the error was called from try.xts?

3) I presume the problem is with the dates, which are not in ISO 8601 format. But I haven't found a way to convert the dates to POSIXct since the dates are only round to days.

4) Any comments to the codes are much appreciated.

I attached with the codes and the sp500components.csv could be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5o0GzWNoY3Q2VfV3E5TGYwZGM/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks for your time and kind help! All the best.

```
library(quantstrat)
library(FinancialInstrument)
library(TTR)

symbols <- read.table("sp500components.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")$V1
symbols <- as.character(symbols) 

currency("USD")
stock(symbols, currency="USD",multiplier=1)

MonthlyAd <- function(x){
  # Converts daily data to monthly and returns only the monthly close 
  # Note: only used with Yahoo Finance data so far
  # Thanks to Joshua Ulrich for the Monthly Ad function
  # 
  # args:
  #   x = daily price data from Yahoo Finance
  #
  # Returns:
  #   xts object with the monthly adjusted close prices

  sym <- sub("\\..*$", "", names(x)[1])
  Ad(to.monthly(x, indexAt = 'lastof', drop.time = TRUE, name = sym))
}

symEnv <- new.env()

f <- function(x) {
  uri    <- "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv"
  symbol <- paste("s",x,sep="=")
  from   <- "a=1&b=1&c=2000"
  to     <- "d=31&e=12&f=2015"
  period <- "g=d"
  ignore <- "ignore=.csv"
  query  <- paste(symbol,from,to,period,ignore,sep="&")
  url    <- paste(uri,query,sep="?")
  try(assign(x,read.csv(url),envir=symEnv))
}

lapply(symbols,f) 

ts <- function(x) {
    x["Date"] <- as.Date.character(x[["Date"]], "%Y-%m-%d")
    x <- xts(x[,-1], order.by = x$Date)
    colnames(x) <- gsub("Adj", "Adjusted", colnames(x))
    assign(symbol, x)
}

eapply(symEnv, ts) 

symbols.close <- do.call(merge, eapply(symEnv, MonthlyAd))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide a reproducible example of the cause of the error, I have to make some guesses. So I assume you're calling `MonthlyAd` on the objects in `symEnv`.

The object created by your `f` function does not have the characteristics that `to.monthly` expects. Namely, the data.frame it creates does not have row names that represent the datetimes for each observation.

There's no problem if you call `MonthlyAd` on the objects created by `eapply(symEnv, ts)`.

```
symList <- eapply(symEnv, ts)
symListMonthly <- lapply(symList, MonthlyAd)
```

There's also no problem if you just use `getSymbols` an the `env` argument. For example:

```
symEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols("SPY;IWM", env = symEnv)
symListMonthly <- eapply(symEnv, MonthlyAd)
```